# Where to find all the classes of installed Android SDK source code?

Tags: android

I installed the Android API 28 Platform in Android Studio's SDK Manager so that I could look through the source code. In the `External Libraries` package in Android Studio, there is a package called `<Android API 28 Platform>`, which I assumed contained the source code.

While looking through the `GLSurfaceView` class, I noticed that the class `EGLLogWrapper` wasn't visible in Android Studio at `External Libraries -> <Android API 28 Platform> -> android.jar -> android -> opengl`, which is where in the package it seemed it should be. However, when I went to Windows File Explorer and searched at `Android -> Sdk -> sources -> android-28 -> android -> opengl`, the class `EGLLogWrapper` (as well as some other classes not shown in Android Studio), were found there.

I found that by right-clicking on `android.jar` (in `<Android API 28 Platform>`) and selecting "Show in Explorer", the File Explorer opens up the location at `Android -> Sdk -> platforms -> android-28`, where the `android.jar` is located. But this doesn't seem to be the source code that I installed. The classes that are visible within Android Studio all show that their File Explorer locations are in `Android -> Sdk -> sources -> android-28` along with the classes that are missing in Android Studio. However, the only source code I can find within Android Studio is packaged under `android.jar`.

So my question is: how can I find the full Android API 28 source code that I installed from the SDK Manager in Android Studio? Because currently what I found in `External Libraries` isn't the full API.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to find the source code from .jar files (unless you decompile). You can find the source code for API 28 here:
https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-28

Comment: It does seem strange that the classes are under a `.jar` but I'm able to look at the source code for the visible classes anyway, although not all the classes are shown. When I open up the File Explorer location of the visible classes, their locations are in the folder path `Android -> Sdk -> sources -> android-28` as opposed to `Android -> Sdk -> platforms -> android-28`. So I don't know if there is a way to just access the `sources` package within Android Studio.